# php array key sorting with strings & numbers

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

```
<?php
$rate=array ( "M100B1000" => "40.00", "M1000B20000" => "80.00", "M500B10000" => "50.00", "MUnlimitedBUnlimited" => "240.00", "M5000BUnlimited" => "120.00 ") ;
ksort($rate);
print_r($rate);
?>
```

It gives sorting rate array..

```
M1000B20000
M100B1000
M5000BUnlimited
M500B10000
MUnlimitedBUnlimited
```

I Need this sorting..

```
M100B1000
M500B10000
M1000B20000
M5000BUnlimited
MUnlimitedBUnlimited
```

Give some ideas...

Comment: do you want it sorted by length of the string or the numeric value inside it?

Comment: the sort does **not** take numbers into account, this is just a simple A-Z string sort comparisson, so `M100B` is not going to be before `M1000B` (extra 0). You will have to manually sort / reg expression this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you want to sort it based on the size of the string if yes take a look at this example

more explanation here http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

```
 function shortestFirst(key($str1), key($str2)) {

        return strlen(key($str1)) - strlen(key($str2));

     }
    $rate=array ( "M100B1000" => "40.00", "M1000B20000" => "80.00", "M500B10000" => "50.00", "MUnlimitedBUnlimited" => "240.00", "M5000BUnlimited" => "120.00 "); 


    uasort($data, 'shortestFirst');
        print_r($data);
        echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: M100B1000,
M500B10000,
M1000B20000,MUnlimitedBUnlimited
M5000BUnlimited, last is change